# Ruby on Rails: Acts as Taggable searching like terms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, acts-as-taggable-on

I'd like to search tags that has similar terms. For instance if there's a tag that has two words, `christmas shopping`, I'd like to search all that has similar tags with christmas or shopping.

right now I have this

```
@tag = Boom.tagged_with(params[:tag], :any => true, :wild => true)
```

Is this possible? With just SQL there's such as thing with `%`or `LIKE` but can this be applied somehow with `acts as taggable`?

Thanks

Comment: could you explain this question a little bit more?. For me wild option is exactly what you search. like write in documentation: "You can also use :wild => true option along with :any or :exclude option. It will looking for %awesome% and %cool% in sql."

Comment: @Adeptus well, i've tested this `:wild` option, but because its two words (`christmas shopping`), its not working. Its supposed to work in this case as well?

Comment: I checked and two words string is wrong. but if you make params[:tag].split(" ") it should work

Comment: @Adeptus thanks, this works. Would you like to answer it so I can send you some points? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like we discussed upper in comments: if you make params[:tag].split(" ") it will be working.